# Checking equality with ComplexInfinity and testing whether a function is (mathematically) undefined

Tags: programming

This seems ridiculously basic, but I cannot find anywhere explaining how to do it.

If you evaluate certain undefined functions like `1/0` or `Tan[\[Pi]/2]`, Mathematica evaluates to `ComplexInfinity`. For some reason, however, the following expression does not act as expected:

```
1/0 == ComplexInfinity
```

This results in

> ComplexInfinity == ComplexInfinity

rather than the expected

> True

So the question is, how do you test whether a function evaluates to `ComplexInfinity`, or better yet, how do you test if a function is (mathematically, not programmatically) undefined?

Comment: If you need to test if something returns `ComplexInfinity`, you can use `something === ComplexInfinity`.  This is a structural test that'll only return True if the two symbols are identical.  It's not a mathematical test like == is.

Comment: I think the reason why ComplexInfinity == ComplexInfinity doesn't evaluate is that the direction in the complex plane is considered unknown.  Check [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DirectedInfinity.html).

Comment: Something I didn't know before: it seems all of `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, `ComplexInfinity` are just special printed forms of `DirectedInfinity`.  Check their FullForm or their Head: they have structure.

Comment: @Szabolcs Probably enough info in your three comments to combine them in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why `ComplexInfinity == ComplexInfinity`, let's look at how *Mathematica* handles infinities.  All of `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, `ComplexInfinity` are just displayed forms of `DirectedInfinity`:

```
In[1]:= FullForm /@ {Infinity, -Infinity, ComplexInfinity}
Out[1]= {DirectedInfinity[1], DirectedInfinity[-1], DirectedInfinity[]}
```

[`DirectedInfinity[z]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DirectedInfinity.html) represents an infinite quantity in the direction of `z` on the complex plane.  [`ComplexInfinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexInfinity.html) is `DirectedInfinity[]`; i.e., an infinite quantity with an unknown direction.  The reason it cannot be compared is that *the direction is unknown*.

---

If you need to test for `ComplexInfinity` in particular, you can use

```
something === ComplexInfinity
```

[`===`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameQ.html) is a structural test that, unlike [`==`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html), does not take any mathematical meaning into account.

---

Finally, for your purpose, I think `NumericalQ` (your answer) is a very good solution.

Comment: Posted answer per request.

Comment: If all you want is to test if an input is infinite: `MatchQ[(* stuff *), _DirectedInfinity]`. +1 of course.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do this, simply test the value of the function with `NumericQ` to determine if it evaluates to a number or not. I would still be interested to know what sort of object or entity ComplexInfinity is that I can't test whether it is equal to itself with `==`.